# Developing SaaS, how can we evenly distribute users created on each region (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, saas

Currently I am developing a SaaS product which will make use of AWS to host the EC2 servers and RDS databases. Every region will have their own EC2 servers and RDS databases but the login will be done from a centralized database (this database will store the encrypted database details to where the user data is stored so the application can make a connection to the database).

For example, Asia region can have 5 EC2 servers and 5 RDS databases while US can have 10 of each. When a database in a region reaches 10,000 users then the next user who registered to Asia region will be redirected to the newly created 6th EC2 server and have their data store in the newly created 6th RDS database.

I am stuck at the part where I need to know that the next user will be the 10,001 user of the latest database that is created and therefore perform the necessary actions to register this user in the new database. I am thinking of creating a script to load get the count of users in every single database (filter by the region from the user) and then decide from there. I wish to know if there are better ways to archive this? Is there any technologies that can help me in this (like services from AWS where they can do this automatically)?

Comment: Chances are you *really* don't want to do things this way.

Comment: What problem do you think you're solving by doing this?

Comment: We are planning to prepare the product to handle huge amount of traffic and load. Currently I am looking for a way to distribute user to different databases just like how Salesforce did it (multiple user in multiple database).

Comment: @ceejayoz Do you have any advise for me? I am really open to suggestions right now. Thanks!

Comment: To deal with global load, look into using read replicas, sharding, latency-based routing, etc.

Comment: @Norman I advise you to avoid premature optimization. 90% of SaaS apps don't get out of the 1-2 server range for requirements. Those that do still don't need a system this convoluted - even Facebook doesn't shard like this, to my knowledge. Spend the (expensive) time elsewhere and just scale up the RDS a few times.

Comment: @MattHouser Yup I will be using those. But I am just stuck at the part on assigning users to different databases based on the number of users currently present in the old database. I think Salesforce also does this but how did they know at the point of registration they need to move this new user to a new database?

Comment: Facebook, Google, Twitter, Amazon, Salesforce etc. started small, and implemented *sensible* scaling measures *when they became necessary*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am starting to feel that I am actually worrying too much right now.

Comment: Also, tying users to regions is a bad idea unless it's for a good reason. What if I registered in Asia, then traveled to US? Now all my data is half a world away.

Comment: @MattHouser You have a point there, I am so silly. Haha!

Comment: It's a common pitfall. Start with a single RDS (making multi-AZ will give you high availability) and a couple web servers in one region, put CloudFront in front of it for better performance overseas, and go from there as needed, not before. :-)